# Understanding the subsets without consecutive integers are counted with fibonacci numbers

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm working my way though a section on Second-Order Linear Homogenous Recurrence Relations with Constant Coefficients. There is an example that I do not understand. The part I'm having trouble with is highlighted in red.

[image]

Why does $n\in A$ mean that $A - {n}$ would be counted in $a_{n-2}$. Part b makes sense because the biggest possible element in A is then $n-1$ which would be counted in $a_{n-1}$ if is smaller than that, it would still be counted in $a_{n-1}$. These are the only two possible cases so acceptance of a) is all I'm really missing to complete my understanding. Can anyone help me understand why a) is true?

Answer (score 2):

If $n \in A$, then $n-1 \not\in A$ (otherwise, $A$ will contain consecutive integers $n-1$ and $n$). Thus maximum possible value in $A-\{n\}$ is $n-2$ and $A-\{n\}$ can now be chosen in $a_{n-2}$ ways.

Comment: Ahhh. So it just uses the condition that no integers can be consecutive and then similar logic to the part b). Thanks man. I'll accept your answer ASAP.